# Redis, Real Time usecase

Tags: redis, labview

Situation
Working on use case for Redis, where are reading Redis data structure string and writing a different string key every 50 ms. Have two different machines accessing these string data structures at the 50 ms rate. Are wanting to have this be able to run for over 3 days with all access times under 10 ms. This is allowing data transfer between two different Real time systems. This transfer must always be under 30 ms, and must run for over 3 days with out any access times above 10 ms.

The issue that I seeing is that if I run Redis from VM (fedora workstation) and the host is windows 10. That 99% of the time are able to be under 1 ms in access times, but are seeing spikes in access times that go above 40 ms, and some above 60 ms.   Have seen the low frequency of access times spikes when are running Redis, in Windows and the worst(Over 200 ms) when are running Redis in separate hardware running fedora using 1 GB ethernet). In all cases have turned saving off from redis.conf.

Opportunity:
Is there a redis.conf entry or other option to set that would improve the consistency in access times?

Is there a hardware or software configuration that would be recommended that would allow this access time to be realized?

Thank you in advance for any help that can be suggested,

Paul

This has been tested using clients of Python, and LabVIEW